# Combine 2 MySQL results with an additional column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 MySQL queries that generated the 2 results below:

```
SELECT * FROM `full_schedule`;
```

result:

```
    Date   | Time
____________________ 
27-06-2017 | 0800
27-06-2017 | 0900
27-06-2017 | 1000
27-06-2017 | 1100
27-06-2017 | 1200
27-06-2017 | 1300
27-06-2017 | 0800
28-06-2017 | 0900
28-06-2017 | 1000
28-06-2017 | 1100
28-06-2017 | 1200
28-06-2017 | 1300
```

and:

```
SELECT * from `available_schedule`;
```

result:

```
    Date   | Time 
___________________ 
27-06-2017 | 0800
27-06-2017 | 0900
28-06-2017 | 1000
```

Question 1:
How to cross check both results and to have the result with addition column like the following?

Question 2:
Possible to combine all queries into 1?

```
    Date   | Time | Status
___________________________ 
27-06-2017 | 0800 | 1
27-06-2017 | 0900 | 1
27-06-2017 | 1000 | 0
27-06-2017 | 1100 | 0
27-06-2017 | 1200 | 0
27-06-2017 | 1300 | 0
27-06-2017 | 0800 | 0
28-06-2017 | 0900 | 0
28-06-2017 | 1000 | 1
28-06-2017 | 1100 | 0
28-06-2017 | 1200 | 0
28-06-2017 | 1300 | 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the cardinality of your tables is **full_schedule 1 : 1 available_schedule**, you can perform a left join and create a calculated field for Status based on the existence of any column in the table on the right (available_schedule in this example):

```
SELECT A.Date,
       A.Time,
       (case when B.Time IS NULL then 0 else 1 end) as Status
FROM   full_schedule A
LEFT JOIN
       available_schedule B
ON     A.Date=B.Date
AND    A.Time=B.Time
<YOUR_WHERE_CLAUSE>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
 (SELECT f.*, 0 as Status FROM full_schedule as f)
 UNION
 (SELECT a.*, 1 as Status from available_schedule as a);
```

As you can see, answer of your both questions is yes. You can add an extra column (for the answer of first question) and using `UNION` to combine the set of the results as you removed the duplicated of each table in final result.

Comment: May I know how to set the 1 in a.Status always overwrite f.Status?

Comment: no. it is not overwrite anything. And the result, would be exactly as you write.